# UISwipeGestureRecognizer state always Ended

Tags: ios, ios9, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a custom interactive transition triggered by a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but the state is always `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, so I can't use it to control the animation.

Apple's documentation says `Some of these states are not applicable to discrete gestures` but they don't say which states are available to `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/state]

Does `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` only have one state or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swipe gestures aren't continuous. When they recognize a swipe, they fire and then they're done. If you want a transition that happens as you slide your finger, you need to use a pan gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about swipe gestures, but this one works better in my situation: `UIPanGestureRecognizer`